# Docbook XSL – HTML customization layer – unwanted breaks in result document

Tags: html, xslt, docbook

*Moving this question to a different thread, as requested.*

I'm trying to customize DocBook XSL's HTML output.

After a docbook `<table>` element, the stylesheets generate this code:

```
<div class="table">
    [...]
</div>
<p>
    <br class="table-break">
</p>
```

This induces unwanted spaces in the HTML output and I can't find where this code comes from as a search for "table-break" in the DocBook XSL comes up with no results. How would I go about getting rid of this code?

Thanks!

~Slampisko

Comment: Have you checked your customization layer?

Comment: I wrote it myself. Nothing indicates that this code should be put behind tables…

Comment: The `<br class="table-break">` bit comes from formal.xsl. Search for `<br class="{$class}-break"/>`. I cannot explain the wrapping `<p>` element though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This information is directed at Docbook XSL 1.77.1. This may not match up with your version, especially given that your post table break element is wrapped with `<p>`:

As mentioned by mzjn, the formal.xsl file has what you're looking for. `formal.object` is a named template that is called when you specify a CALS table (or embed a graphic/mediaobject). Within this template there is a test to check if a break element should be added afterward. There is a global parameter (top of the file) that controls this behaviour. It is enabled by default:

```
<xsl:param name="formal.object.break.after">1</xsl:param>
```

You can redefine this by specifying the parameter to your XSLT processor, with Saxon, for example, it would take the form:

```
java -jar saxon.jar file.xml your.customisation.xsl formal.object.break.after=0
```

You can probably also shadow it from within your customisation by redefining `formal.object.break.after` after you have imported the base stylesheet.

Comment: @Slampisko, where did the wrapping `<p>` element come from?

Comment: The explanation for the existence of this parameter is in this commit: https://github.com/docbook/xslt10-stylesheets/commit/28bb4fded135b6e43cd06948ca3294c41b8009d7